# no me agarra la conexion laravel por medio de xampp

Tags: laravel, xampp, .env

hola soy nueva creando un proyecto de laravel vi en youtube pero en el .env le puse esto:  pero no me agarra la conexión :c

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:cYpOAJDRYabf1ILjN351GiTtiHafGcfhKm42mzqldSk=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sistema-de-ticket-casos
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**como le hago para conectarme a laravel como lo configuro ?**

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.